# Why is continuity of Q(g(x)) needed in this chain rule proof on Wikipedia?

Tags: calculus, chain-rule

I am looking at the first proof of the chain rule on Wikipedia:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chain_rule#First_proof

In the body of the proof, you will see that the author has defined a function $Q(y)$ = \begin{cases}
\frac{f(y) - f(g(a))}{y - g(a)}, & y \neq g(a), \\
f'(g(a)), & y = g(a).
\end{cases}

so that we can rewrite the difference quotient for $f(g(x))$ as

$$Q(y)\ {[g(x) - g(a)]\over(x - a)}$$

and avoid dividing by zero in our proof of the chain rule. $Q(y)$ is then evaluated at $g(x)$ and has its limit taken as $x \to a$ in the final step of the proof.

Here's the problem: It seems to me both that

(i) $Q(g(x))\ \bullet \ {[g(x) - g(a)]\over(x - a)}$ will always be equal to the difference quotient for $f(g(x))$ regardless of what value we assign to it in the case that $y = g(a)$, given that both expressions will evaluate to 0, and

(ii) the limit of $Q(g(x))$ will always evaluate to $f'(g(a))$ as $x \to a$, since $\lim_{x\to a}$$f(g(x)) - f(g(a))  \over g(x) - g(a)$ = $f'(g(a))$.

As a result, I don't see the harm in choosing any arbitrary value for $Q(y)$ when $y = g(a)$ - it seems that $Q$ doesn't actually need to be a continuous function for the proof to work. Intuitively, I feel that there must be something wrong with statement (ii), but I can't place a finger on precisely what the issue is. Hoping I can get some help on this and understand if/why $Q(g(x))$ has to be a continuous function for this proof to work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It may be possible that there is a sequence $(x_n)_x$ such that $x_n \to a, x_n>a$ for all $n$ but $g(x_n)=g(a)$ for all $n$. So, (ii) does not hold: We then have
$$
Q(g(x_n)) = Q(g(a)) = \text{the value we set for the case $y=g(a)$}
$$

**Edit**: A simple example in which this can happen, is if $g$ is constant.

Another example would be
$$
g(x) = \begin{cases}\sin\left(\frac{1}{x}\right) x^2 & \text{if $x\neq 0$}\\0 & \text{else}\end{cases}
$$
This function is differentiable at $a=0$ (check :)) and you can set $x_n:= \frac{1}{\pi n}$ to obtain a sequence as described above.

Comment: Hm, so an example of this could be one of those funky sinusoidals where the value keeps oscillating as $x \to a$? In a case like that, wouldn't the limit of Q as $x \to a$ simply be undefined because the function does not approach a fixed value, therefore suggesting an undefined derivative as well?

Comment: @Dan I added a simple example. you could as well take some funky sinusoidal function, but continuity will always be assured by the assumption that $g$ has to be differentiable at $a$

Comment: Oh, I think I've got a grasp of the issue now! We have to think of it as: $Q(g(x)) = f'(g(a))$ ANY TIME $g(x) = g(a)$ within this neighborhood as $x \to a$, not just "at this one specific point where $g(x) = g(a)$" (e.g. $x = a = 0$). Failing to define Q(g(x)) this way, we might well end up with a function that does not have a limit as $x \to a$, so our proof would fail. It would be fine to set $Q(g(x)) = some random value$ if we ALWAYS knew it would be the case that $g(x) = g(a)$ _only_ when x = a. However, examples like the one above make it clear that such a practice would not generalize.

Comment: I guess the only concern that remains, then, is whether or not we are justified in setting (())=′(()) for _all_ values where ()=(). Isn't this something that would demand justification of its own? :-/ (I guess what I'm not yet sold on here is that defining Q this way indeed makes Q a continuous function. And also, does it even matter if Q is continuous at all the points $x_n$, or is that basically meaningless?)

Comment: It doesn't matter whether or not $Q$ is continuous, the important thing is that $Q$ is _continuos at_ $a$.

Comment: Yes! That's exactly what I was thinking last night. Took me a while to get there, but now it seems so obvious. We're not trying to ensure continuity everywhere, we're just trying to ensure the limit at $a$ exists and is what we'd expect it to be. As a result of that, it just so happens that Q ends up being continuous at a. Perfect! Thanks so much, Jakob! Funny how tiny little errors in thinking can lead to so much confusion. xD